# Multiple parameter servers are not sharing the load when running TensorFlow distributed

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, distributed-system

We're trying to run cifar10 over multiple machines with multiple parameter servers and workers. We can successfully perform distributed training. Before training starts, all the workers *wait* for all parameter servers to be initialized. On observing network traffic using iftop it seems that all the traffic goes to a single parameter server (negligible traffic is observed on other parameter servers) The code for setting up the workers and parameters is below:

```
#Construct the cluster and start the server
ps_spec = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
worker_spec = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

# Get the number of workers.
num_workers = len(worker_spec)
num_ps = len(ps_spec)

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_spec,"worker": worker_spec})

with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(ps_tasks=num_ps,  worker_device=worker_device, ps_device="/job:ps/cpu:0", cluster=cluster)):
```

The entire code for cifar10 distributed training can be found here: https://github.com/nanditav/15712-TensorFlow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_replica.py

Comment: You could try a different device placement strategy for your variables, such as `tf.contrib.training.GreedyLoadBalancingStrategy`, see `tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/device_setter_test.py`

Comment: Thanks ! Based on the source you pointed out I made the following changes:                                                                                                      `with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device=worker_device, ps_device="/job:ps/cpu:0", cluster=cluster, ps_strategy=tf.contrib.training.GreedyLoadBalancingStrategy)):`
It returns: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GreedyLoadBalancingStrategy'`

Comment: your version of TensorFlow is too old

Comment: Thanks ! updating from 0.11 to 0.12 solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

There's an example of using alternative strategies in [device_setter_test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e7508b6efd51f7cfed32ff277e805f8ea60a7a48/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/device_setter_test.py#L33), ie

```
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
    cluster=self._cluster_spec,
    ps_strategy=tf.contrib.training.GreedyLoadBalancingStrategy(
        2, _load_fn))):
  u = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 2]))
  v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1]))
  w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 2]))
  x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 3]))
  a = v + w
```

It's easy/common to write your own balancing strategy by starting with the code in `GreedyLoadBalancingStrategy`

What may happen sometimes is that a single variable is huge, in which case you would need to break variable into smaller pieces first manually or using `PartitionedVariable`